# Cookieless tracking

Tags: php, caching, cookies, tracking

I'm working on university final year's project which includes website visitor tracking (not conversion tracking so server-to-server postback tracking isn't of my interest). Obviously it's dead simple to implement using cookies, however as a fallback I'd like to implement cookieless tracking. I know it's not reliable, but the articles I've read were quite outdated so maybe things have changed and there's some clever way to do it.

I understand that the only possible footprint that could be used is a combination of UA(I could store browser update information because the UA header won't be matched if it's been updated so I could somehow figure out that the same visitor just updated his browser) and IP (and timestamps maybe? if so how? what patterns I should be looking at?), but I'm starting to look into client-side data caching which could be sent to the server using AJAX or some other alternative.

What I'm looking for are ideas and tips that could help me built this sort of tracking system.

I'll be storing each visitors profile in a database so that I could analyse each visitor individually. So on page view, I'm going to lookup that visitor and if he already exists I'll continue to store data linked to him.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: even though everything in my body tries to avoid telling you the link... because my body hates "you" tracking, identifying, profile generating glass user "people". But here ya go: http://www.scatmania.org/2012/04/24/visitor-tracking-without-cookies/ - insert peter parkers uncle quote [here].

Comment: were you talking about "Remember, with great power, comes great responsibility"? haha, this is for educational purposes only so I don't see any threats regarding legal/privacy rights :) Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: yes thats the quote I meant. And the problem with education is this... you can't rewind progress/knwonledge creation. You discover a super easy way to track users without the hassle from "known to most and blocked by some mainstream addons" so you can collect your data anyway. But of course you don't think about evil, you want to supply the user with better advertisment/product recommodations... we implemented some fancy big-data algorithsms in our university and I am greatly worried what you can do with all the data collected. Thats why I am so grumpy toward that topic

Comment: Yeah, true. However at least now, I don't see how the data could be used (for an evil cause) apart from what you said, better advertisement, recommendations and website optimization (based on the preferences of the majority of visitors). You wouldn't have personal data. So where's the issue? Freedom to not be tracked?

Comment: Yes, freedom of choice is a great matter here (or to me atleast). In my freetime I spend my time ordering porn, books about little kittens and books on knitting a kilt from amazon... just to mess around with their data collection crazyness. There are SO MANY ways to gather information about the user from a professional way. And there are so less options if you want to bypass those. You always have to be ahead of the data collectors... and that really tires me somtimes (guess how much fun surfing the web without ANY browser addon like javascript/flash is these days)

Comment: Yeah we all order porn just to mess with their data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented a basic tracking based on IP address, but as it collects all the other information it can (browser, OS, screen resolution, colour depth, flash version, etc) so it's definitely possible to define a user by a collection of these data points.

I tend to store the raw data and then use queries after to perform the analytics to make it faster, but it depends whether or not you need to store other information that you actually use throughout that users visit.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by raw? Not hashed? And yes every single bit of information has to be stored and would be used later on.